# ASP FileUpload Silent Fail

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I'm having a problem using using FileUpload for large files.  If I upload a small file (~10kB), it works fine.  Uploading a large file (~60MB) does not throw an exception, it just reloads the page.  Before anyone asks: `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600" waitChangeNotification="1" maxWaitChangeNotification="3600" requestValidationMode="2.0" />`

Page:

```
<%@ AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/LargeFileUploadControl.aspx.cs" Inherits="LargeFileUploadControl" %>
<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="theOnlyLabel" runat="server" Text="Uploaded files will go to a place"/><br />
<asp:FileUpload ID="theOnlyUpload" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="theOnlyButton" onClick="StartUpload" Text="Upload" runat="server" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class LargeFileUploadControl:Page
{
public string _uploadDir;

/// <summary>
/// Content loaded event handler
/// </summary>
protected override void  OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    _uploadDir = "D:\\web\\tikt.imaginuity.com\\TIKT\\media\\TIKT\\Global Large Uploads\\";
    theOnlyLabel.Text = "Uploaded files will go to " + _uploadDir;
}


protected void StartUpload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (theOnlyUpload.HasFile)
    {
        theOnlyLabel.Text = "Uploading...";
        theOnlyUpload.SaveAs(_uploadDir + theOnlyUpload.FileName);
        theOnlyLabel.Text = "File saved to " + _uploadDir + theOnlyUpload.FileName;
    }
    else
    {
        theOnlyLabel.Text = "No file to upload";
    }

    return;
}
}
```

**EDIT :** I had already tried the accepted answer below, or so I thought.  Looking again I discovered that there were *two* `<system.webServer>` sections in my web.config that both needed the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fix your issue, if you are using iis7. I tested on upload file size more than 400MB,

Add the following configuration in your web.config file under  element.

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is on IIS7, you also need to reconfigure that to accept files > ~30MB: http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/iis7-post-40-adjusting-file-upload-size-in-iis7

Answer (score 0):

make executionTimeout="9000" in your  tag...

Answer (score 0):

Check out SlickUpload: http://slickupload.com/

Even if you aren't going to use the free version, they do a very nice job of talking about mitigating for the request limits in IIS 6 and IIS 7, in their docs:

http://slickupload.com/documentation/installation

In particular, browser to that page and do a Control-F for "requestFiltering" and look at the section they mention adding to web.config.