# File uploads when run locally, but not when on the internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am able to upload files to the proper directory on my local computer, but when I try to use the pages on the webserver, it doesn't upload the file, nor put them in the database like it is supposed to. All my other file upload controls work as well as inserting it into the database. Here is the relevant code:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/PlaceImages/") + filename);
UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Complete!";
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TravelJoansDB.mdb;";
string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO BlogEntryItems (BlogID, Picture, PicText1) VALUES (?,?,?)";
int blogID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);

con.Open();
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogID", blogID);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", filename);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PicText1", txtPhotoText.Text);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you set the proper permissions for the PlaceImages folder?

Comment: Yeah, that was my first problem that I figured out earlier.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Also is there a reason you are using jet drivers? If your local machine is 32bit and the server is 64bit then that might be the problem bc jet is not compatible with 64bit processes. You would need to configure IIS to run your site in 32bit mode and make sure the jet driver is installed, or I would recommend using a different driver since I believe the jet drivers were killed awhile back.

Comment: Please advise the error that you get.

Comment: Actually, there is no error. And @BateTech, the same exact lines work on the other pages I have in the site.

Comment: Did you happen to copy this page from another existing page? I've seen some odd issues before if you copy the aspx and aspx.cs files and rename them but don't change the page class name. Another option might be clearing the temporary asp.net files on the server to make sure an old version of the page is not cached. Files are located %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework <OR Framework64 is 64bit>\ <VERSION> \Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: I don't think I have access to those files on the GoDaddy server. It works on my laptop, which is 64-bit. I'm not sure what the webserver on GoDaddy is.

Comment: I most likely did copy and paste, but I only ever copy and paste what I posted because I've run into the class error before. In any event, the classes and references are correct.

Comment: How large is the file you are uploading?  Could be this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705474/asp-fileupload-silent-fail

Comment: @Joseph Also here is more info about request filtering.  It looks like IIS will return a 404 if the request filtering is the issue.  If you open IE dev tools (F12) and go to network tab and click "start capturing" then try to upload the file.  Then click on the request row that shows up and check the response header to see if it returns a 404. http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Comment: I don't allow the file to be larger than 10MB. @BateTech